# Port forwarding / SSH tunneling - explain this to a beginner

Tags: linux, unix, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am attempting to forward traffic from port **RP** on remote host **RH** to port **LP** on my local box **LH**.

I have tried running

> ssh -R (**RP**):localhost:(**LP**) -N user@(**LH**)

from the remote server. This creates an SSH tunnel, but it does not seem to do what I want it to. That is to say traffic to http://(**RH**):(**RP**)/webpage is returning a 404.

Is there any way I can check if and to where the traffic is forwarded?

It seems from some of the guides I have read that I need to set up tunneling on my local box, but that does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this site](http://jcsalterego.github.com/2011/02/04/getting-comfortable-with-ssh.html) to have an excellent explanation of SSH port forwarding:

> There are two types of tunnels, local (-L) and remote (-R), which are named after the entry point of the traffic.

You could start the tunnel from either end and forward appropriately; I'm going to demonstrate it starting from **LH** and setting up an entry port on **RH**.

In this case, you're saying you want to have traffic enter at **RP** on **RH**, and exit at **LP** on **LH**. If you think of it as a tunnel or pipe, then the entry ("ingress") port would be on **RH**, and the exit ("egress") port would be on **LH**.

The command you need to run (from localhost) should be:

```
$ ssh -R <RP>:<LH>:<LP> <RH>
```

This will connect to **RH** and ask ssh on that side to set up a listening port there on **RP**; the ssh process you just ran will then take those packets and inject them locally to **LP** on **LH**.

**Note**: If **RP** is <= 1024, you'll need to have root privileges on **RH** to start the tunnel.